# Facebook Audience Network Bidding integration in Android

Tags: android, admob, facebook-audience-network

I hope many of you are using Facebook Audience Network for app monetization. I am having some questions regarding their latest new "bidding" strategy.

I want to integrate AdMob as a mediation partner with Facebook Audience Network. After reading the documentation mentioned, it seems like I have to add both (AdMob + FAN) SDK's and make ad requests separately from both of these. Can someone please confirm for me if that is true?
Does that mean if I want to integrate multiple mediation partners I'll have to add multiple SDKs? Don't you think it will increase the app size unnecessarily?

Please share your thoughts if any of you have implemented Bidding in their Android App.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You have to add FAN mediation sdk and google admob sdk. You don't have to request ads for Facebook audiences network just initialize the audience network sdk..
Make sure that you have added Facebook audiences network placement as an ad source in Admob oepn bidding section.

Comment: Okay but I want to use Audience Network as my primary ad network. I want to make requests to Audience Network. I want nothing to do with AdMob.

Comment: You can't do that you need to use a mediation partner for showing audience network ads

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking to add facebook audience network to my app and came across your question. Have you get the answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE : Use Real Ads Id and Configure your Mobile Device on Admob and Facebook Dashboard**

**1 —> add dependancies to buid.gradle (App)**

```
if your sdk version is below 31 



 //    admob
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.4.0'
    //facebook mediation
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.8.0.0'
```

If your sdk version is 31 or above

```
  //    admob
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.6.0’
    //facebook mediation
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.8.0.1’
```

**2 —> Configure your app**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

---

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

**3 —> Add meta tag to manifest**

```
 <!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
```

**4 —> Initialise ads**

```
    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
  @Override
  public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {

  }
});

    AdSettings.addTestDevice("ID”);//
    
    MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(
            new RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("ID"))
                    .build());//
```

**5—> for Testing Check which ad network adapter class loaded the ad**

```
public void onAdLoaded() {
  Log.d("Banner adapter class name: " + ad.getResponseInfo().getMediationAdapterClassName());
}
```

**6 —> Additional code required**

In manifest

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

**network_security_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
<domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
</domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

**7 —> Test your implementation using mediation Test Suite**

Add dependenceis to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.ads:mediation-test-suite:2.0.0'
```

Include the google() repository in your top-level build.gradle file:

If not there
—————————————————————

```
repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
   }
```

———————————————————————

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
   }
}
```

**Launch using below code**

```
MediationTestSuite.launch(MainActivity.this);
```

**8 —> Test Ids**

```
<string name="app_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713</string>
<string name="app_open_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3419835294</string>

<string name="banner_preview">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
<string name="banner_my_creation">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
<string name="banner_extract">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
<string name="banner_main">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>

<string name="interstitial_my_creation">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712</string>
<string name="interstitial_save">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712</string>

<string name="native_main">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110</string>
<string name="native_preview">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110</string>

<string name="ad_attribution">Ad</string>
```